# Android FloatActionButton: how to make it stick out of a View?

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay, floating-action-button

I have a FloatActionButton that have to stick out a bit from the view that contains it, but it becomes cutted.

How can I obtain it to get out a bit from the container?

*Example Image*

[image]

*This is the complete code of the Layout, including the Coordinator Layout and the FAB.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/activity_show_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/add_text_to_media_image"/>

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@color/black_overlay"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
          />

      <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
          android:id="@+id/add_text_to_media_detail"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom">
          <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/black_overlay"
              android:paddingTop="8dp"
              android:paddingBottom="8dp"
              android:paddingLeft="16dp"
              android:paddingRight="16dp"
              android:id="@+id/add_text_to_media_text_container">
              <EditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:hint="Aggiungi una descrizione..."
                  android:textColorHint="@color/material_grey_300"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:id="@+id/add_text_to_media_text"/>
          </RelativeLayout>
          <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
              android:id="@+id/add_text_to_media_button"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:fabSize="normal"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
              app:layout_anchor="@+id/add_text_to_media_text_container"
              app:layout_anchorGravity="right"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="-27dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
              />
      </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


  </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your view taller with a transparent background and change the background of your edittext to the darker color if you want